# How to execute page methods when using custom route handlers?

Tags: asp.net, pagemethods, custom-routes

When the path refers to the actual folder structure and points to the page it's not a problem, i.e. "/Default.aspx/MyMethod", however if "/" brings up "Default.aspx", then "/MyMethod" means something different. Is it even possible at all?

A possible solution, and probably a better one, is to use a web service, which is what I'm using at the moment.

Comment: That doesn't really help answer the question, but thanks for the link, nice article.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following:

```
PageMethods.set_path('/yourpage.aspx');
```

[I found this solution here](http://brentman.com/blog/2009/11/14/asp-net-pagemethods-break-when-using-asp-net-routing)

Comment: It looks like it's only applicable if using a built in framework, thanks for the tip though.

Comment: It is worth noting that this needs to be set in javascript on the clientside.